# 3D printer X-axis sometimes binds up whilst printing

Tags: prusa-i3, x-axis

My MK2s has developed a strange problem where the X-axis will bind up whilst printing. This causes it to layer shift. The strange thing is I can move the X-axis manually. It doesn't bind up and feels smooth. But halfway into a print, I heard the X-axis make a scrapping sound that's distinctive to it struggling to move.

The bearings are still the original bearings but have had very little use. Maybe 30 hours of printing if that.

I have already taken the X-axis apart and cleaned it with some bike cleaner( didn't have enough alcohol to form a bath. Before I cleaned it, it wasn't moving smoothly along the rails. Now it does move smoothly on the rails but did bind up mid-print.

I have checked the X-axis belt, it doesn't seem to be too loose or tight. I tighten the screws that adjust the belt tension by hand so I doubt it's too tight. It makes the distinctive sound of a guitar string when you run your finger across the belt.

I am thoroughly confused. Could it be a bad bearing?